# How I can clear memory when use Camera?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, camera

I'm trying to create a camera app but got memory leak.
I can clear cache of PhotoLibrary but cant clear cache of Camera.
App will down after take about 40 photos.
How can I clear memory?

```
// After taking a picture
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] != nil {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        var orientation: Int?

        if isNewPhoto == true {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(BaseResultViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata] as? NSDictionary
            orientation = metadata?.objectForKey("Orientation") as? Int
        }
        else {
            switch image.imageOrientation.rawValue {
                case 0:
                    orientation = 1
                case 1:
                    orientation = 3
                case 2:
                    orientation = 8
                case 3:
                    orientation = 6
                default:
                    break
            }
        }

        let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let imageName = "\(uuid).PNG"
        let jpgImageName = "\(uuid)-thumb.JPG"
        let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)
        let localPath = relationData.setFile(imageName, data: data!)
        let _ = relationData.setFile(jpgImageName, data: jpgData!)

        getViewIns()?.hideActionSheet()
        baseModel.saveValuable(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: localPath), orientation: orientation)
        prepareSegue(true)
        resetValuable()
    }
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: i can clear cache of PhotoLibrary with these code but cant clear Camera.  
`func clearCache() {
        SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearMemory()
        SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearDisk()
    } `

Comment: try **URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()** This is Used to clear all cache of iOS App

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I tried but it didnt work.
Does it mean this problem is not due to cache?

Comment: There is no general way to free memory. You should check your leak with _Instuments_. You have probably cyclic references or something else which causes leaks.

Comment: What type is `relationData` and what do you use it for? If this is keeping references to the `data`/`jpgData` objects you pass in the data won't get freed and you'll eventually run out of mem.

Comment: thanks clemens. I tried use Instuments but iits crushed....  maybe i should fix it

Comment: thanks dr_barto. im using to keep references to the data/jpdgData. i try to clean memory with  `SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearMemory() SDImageCache.sharedImageCache().clearDisk() } ` Does it work or not?